# how to remove gtk assistant "Finish" button and rename "Apply" button in assistant's action box

Tags: c, gtk3, gtkassistant

Using Gtk3 in c.
When "confirm" type page is not the last page, clicking the "Apply" button causes  the "Finish" action button to appear on all subsequent pages. Clicking the "Finish" button closes the assistant.
I have not been able to find any description of this action button.
Upon further research, I have found the solution which enables me to remove annoying button and also rename other buttons in the action box. The changes are global (i.e. apply to all pages).

```
    GtkWidget *dummy = gtk_label_new ("");                                      // dummy label
    gtk_assistant_add_action_widget (GTK_ASSISTANT (assistant), dummy);         // add dummy label to action box
    GtkWidget *action_box = gtk_widget_get_parent (dummy);                      // get pointer to action box
    gtk_assistant_remove_action_widget (GTK_ASSISTANT (assistant), dummy);      // remove dummy label
    GtkWidget *lbl = gtk_test_find_label (action_box, "Apply");                 // find label "Apply"
    GtkWidget *apl_btn = gtk_widget_get_parent (lbl);                           // get pointer to button with label "Apply"
    gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON(apl_btn), "Start");                        // change button's label'
    lbl = gtk_test_find_label (action_box, "Finish");                           // find label "Finish"
    GtkWidget *fin_btn = gtk_widget_get_parent (lbl);                           // get pointer to button with label "Finish"
    gtk_assistant_remove_action_widget (GTK_ASSISTANT (assistant), fin_btn);    // remove "Finish" button
```

I hope this will be useful to other people.